# How to Mock DNS with PHPUnit Bridge?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, dns, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit with Laravel 5 to functionally test my API endpoints.

I noticed my tests are very slow when my laptop is connect to the internet! So I thought it could be the DNS lookup causing this delay.

I required [PHPUnit Bridge](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/phpunit_bridge.html) to Mock the DNS but I don't know what to pass in the parameter inorder to mock my API's subdomain `api.insa.dev` due to the lack of documentaion.

That's what I have so far in my `TestCase` Class `setUp()` function:

```
\Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\DnsMock::withMockedHosts([

    'insa.dev' => [
        [
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            // ... ?!?!?
        ],
    ],

]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think to get this working, first of all you need to call the `register` method on the DnsMock class.

```
\Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\DnsMock::register(App\ClassBeingTested::class);
```

Then, to mock the subdomain, you just put it straight in the mocked hosts:

```
\Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\DnsMock::withMockedHosts([
    'api.insa.dev' => [
        [
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            // ... ?!?!?
        ],
    ],
]);
```